# need help debugging error: invalid conversion from ‘token*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, debugging, struct, compiler-errors, char

Here is my code. It keeps saying I am doing the conversion wrong. What am I doing wrong, and can anyone help me fix this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "StackAr.h"

using namespace std;

struct token{
    int curLine = 1, lastLine = 1;
    char next;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream inf(argv[1]);
    token t1;
    typedef token *t_ptr;                   //assign a pointer to a struct
    t_ptr ptr = &t1;
    t_ptr end;
    StackAr<t_ptr> stack;
    while (inf >> t1.next)
    {
        if (t1.next == '{' || t1.next == '(' || t1.next == '[')
        {
            t1.lastLine = t1.curLine;
            ptr -> next;
            stack.push(ptr);
            new token;
        }
        else if (t1.next == '}' || t1.next == ')' || t1.next == ']')
        {
            t1.lastLine = t1.curLine;
            char previous = stack.topAndPop(); // get previous bracket
            // deal with null
            switch(t1.next)
            {
                case '}' : if (previous != '{') {printError(&t1.next, t1.curLine); return 1;} break;
                case ')' : if (previous != '(') {printError(&t1.next, t1.curLine); return 1;} break;
                case ']' : if (previous != '[') {printError(&t1.next, t1.curLine); return 1;} break;
            }
        }

        if (inf.peek() == '\n')
            t1.curLine++;
    }

    inf.close();

    if (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        char previous = stack.topAndPop()-> next;
        printError(&previous, t1.lastLine);
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "OK" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In function `int main(int, char**)`:

```
mockbalance.cpp:64:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘`token*`’ to ‘`char`’ [-fpermissive]

    char previous = stack.topAndPop(); // get previous bracket

mockbalance.cpp:82:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘`token*`’ to ‘`char`’ [-fpermissive]

    char previous = stack.topAndPop()-> next;
```

edit: the above code has been given a temporary fix as suggested by one of the users in the comment section but i fully recommend using a better structure also look at comments. Given notice any one who plans to use this, ago ahead but keep in mind this code in particular has been already submitted to moss database and should be used to learn.

Comment: Typo? `char previous = stack.topAndPop();` should probably be `char previous = stack.topAndPop()->next;`

Comment: This code makes little sense.  You are pushing a bunch of pointers into the stack that all point to the same `token` instance. Any changes you make to it are reflected in all of the pointers. `new token;` is a memory leak, you are not saving the pointer that `new` returns so you can later `delete` it. Why are you even using a stack of pointers at all? You should use `StackAr<token>` instead of `StackAr<t_ptr>`. Even better, use `std::stack` instead of `StackAr`.

Comment: to the both of you thanks yksisarvinen and for the tip Remy :) about using just token thats very helpful as for why iam using 'stackar' short answer limited by classes but yes both of you gave very useful tip cheers.